# Ignore all files and files in subdirectories except one file

Tags: gitignore

Imagine the following structure:

```
/a/1.txt
/a/2.txt
/a/.keep

/a/b/1.txt
/a/b/2.txt
/a/b/3.txt
/a/b/.keep

/a/b/c/1.txt
/a/b/c/2.txt
/a/b/c/3.txt
/a/b/c/4.txt
/a/b/c/.keep

/d/test.txt
/d/work.txt
```

I want to ignore all files in `a` directory except **`.keep`** files to obtain the following results:

```
/a/.keep

/a/b/.keep

/a/b/c/.keep

/d/test.txt
/d/work.txt
```

My `.gitignore` file that doesn't work:

```
/a/*
!.keep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, you cannot reinclude files at directories ignored by previous rules, according to the [gitignore Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

So this

```
/a/*
!/a/**/.keep
```

will only reinclude `/a/.keep` but not the others.

You'll have to exclude each file pattern under `/a` explictly.

```
/a/**/*.txt
/a/**/.ignore
/a/**/.alsoignore
```

**UPDATE:** Or a better solution is to create the following `.gitgnore` at your `/a` subdirectory:

```
*.*
!.keep
```

(the only drawback is that this solution will also keep files with no extension)

Comment: Can you recommend any other solution?

Comment: Thanks for last solution!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use:

```
/a/*
!**/.keep
```

From the [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) documentation:

> A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For
>   example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same
>   as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar"
>   anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

Comment: There is screenshot from PhpStorm IDE https://www.dropbox.com/s/molz4emls4ixayw/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-09-06%2023.10.11.png?dl=0

Comment: As you can see .gitkeep files still ignoring by git

Comment: The documentation also states " It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined."